# Put registry key object display name to array and sort it

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have plan to:

1. query for all available software from 2 registry keys
2. put the result in one array
3. sort all objects in alphabetical order

Generally objects from 1st and then from 2nd array are sorted by default. However I would like to combine the sorting to receive alphabetical output from both at once.

Any tips?

```
$Software = @()

$regKeys = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
foreach ($key in $regKeys) {
    #Write-Host $key -ForegroundColor Yellow

    Get-ItemProperty $key | 
        Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } |       
        Select-Object DisplayName |
        Write-Output $SoftwareObject.DisplayName
        $Software += $SoftwareObject
}

#Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
```

Comment: your code produces errors at the `Write-Output` line. you did not mention that. have you fixed it in your actual code or is that what you are asking about? ///// if that error is your Question ... **_please add that to your Question._**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why so complicated? Simply query what you're after and sort it.

```
$regKeys = 
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*', 
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'

Get-ItemProperty -Path $regKeys | 
    Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } |
        Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
            Select-Object -Property DisplayName
```

Comment: I have plans to compare installed software database to second database. The second one will include all software and games I ever used/played. The script will check if software configuration files or save games on system drive are newer than on backup drive. If so, the script will copy and override files on backup drive.

Seems to be bit complicated as for my first powershell script ever written.

Comment: Hmmm ... I don't know why you're telling me this. ;-)  Does my code suggestion do what you expected?  I'd recommend going one step at a time. Start small and grow over time with every next step. We've all been there once.